# Mediawiki: Displaying a List does not work with infobox template

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

I created a new template and want to display a list inside my newly coded infobox. To get this working I was told to change the code like in [this German tutorial](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:WikiProjekt_Vorlagen/Anleitung:_Erstellen_einer_Infobox#Zeile_f.C3.BCr_Listen).

This is how my template `Infobox Music` currently looks like:

```
|- 
{{#if: {{{Sänger<includeonly>|</includeonly>}}} |
 {{#ifeq: {{Str left|{{{Sänger}}} }} | *
  |{{!}} style="vertical-align:top;" {{!}}
'''Sänger/in'''
{{!}}
{{{Sänger}}}
  |{{!}} '''Sänger/in'''
{{!}} {{{Sänger}}}
 }}
}}
```

In order to build a new list I edited the source code in a seperate Wiki entry like this:

```
{{Infobox_Music
|Sänger = 
* Lady Gaga
* Michael Jackson
}}
```

Unfortunately, when using both of these settings my list gets displayed with the first item having an * at the beginning just as usual. Here is how it looks in HTML:

```
<tr>
<td> <b>Sänger/in</b>
</td>
<td> * Lady Gaga
<ul><li>Michael Jackson</li></ul>
</td></tr>
```

Did I miss something? What does the line `{{#ifeq: {{Str left|{{{Sänger}}} }}` mean?

**UPDATE**: Here is a snippet of my previous Infobox Music template:

```
{{Infobox Music
    |- 
    {{#if: {{{Sänger|}}} | {{!}} '''Sänger/in''' {{!!}} {{{Sänger}}} }}
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{{Str left|{{{Sänger}}} }}` is the first character of the `Sänger` parameter (see [`{{Str left}}`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Str_left)). `{{#ifeq: {{Str left|{{{Sänger}}} }} | * | ...` is some kind of horrible hack to use a different layout when the parameter is a list; not trying to replicate that will help you preserve your sanity.

`*` will only be interpreted as a list when preceded by a newline. You can prevent stripping of the leading whitespace from the template parameter by doing something like

```
|Sänger = <!---->
* Lady Gaga
```

or you can make sure that in the template `{{{Sänger}}}` is preceded by a newline.

Comment: As recommended I returned to my previous template (code is above). Then I added the "<!---->" snippet in the wiki entry. Again, the * persisted.

I also know that moving the Parameter Sänger into the next line will create a working list, but the problem is, that in case there is only one list item, the element has a gap above

Comment: I also tried copying {{Str left}} with the template I got from wikimedia.org. Even with this change there was this * in the first line.

Comment: Then maybe `<nowiki></nowiki>` or `&#32;`; I forgot which horrible hack people tend to use for this. https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Newlines_and_spaces#Trimming_on_expansion has some even more horrible advice.